# How to get the current page Identifier ( URL key ) in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, page

How can I retrieve the Identifier ( URL key ) of current  page in Magento 2?

Answer (score 5):

Copy this code in any phtml file to get current cms page id and identifier in magento2:

```
<?php

$objectManagerCms = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cmsPage = $objectManagerCms->get('\Magento\Cms\Model\Page');

echo $cmsPage->getIdentifier(); //Current CMS Page Identifier

echo $cmsPage->getId(); //Current CMS Page ID

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can get the page id like this:

```
$pageId = $this->_request->getParam('page_id', $this->_request->getParam('id', false));
```

if you are not in a controller, you need to inject an instance of `\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface` in your class.

You also need to inject an instance of `\Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface` in your class and then you can call:

```
$page = $this->pageRepository->getById($pageId);
$url = $page->getIdentifier();
```

So, your class can look like this:

```
namespaece Your\Namespace\Here;

class SomeClassName extends SomethingElse 
{
    protected $_request; //only if this is not a controller
    protected $pageRepository;
    public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface $pageRepository,
        ....
    )  { 
        ....
        $this->_request = $request; //only if not in a controller
        $this->pageRepository = $pageRepository;
        ....
    }
    public function getCurrentPageUrlKey()
    {
        try {
           $pageId = $this->_request->getParam('page_id', $this->_request->getParam('id', false));
           $page = $this->pageRepository->getById($pageId);  
           return $page->getIdentifier();
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help
I got it working by following method

`public function getIdentifier()
 {
  try {
   $objectManager  = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $configHelper  = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface');
  
            $pageId = $this->_request->getParam('page_id', $this->_request->getParam('id', false));
            $page = $configHelper->getById($pageId);  
            return $page->getIdentifier();
   
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return null;
        }
 }`

Comment: even if it works, using the object manager is not a recommended practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use in Helper like this:

namespace **Your\Namespace\Helper**;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper{

```
protected $objectManager;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
){
    $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
}

public function getCurrentPageIdentifier() {

   $_cmsPage = $this->objectManager->get('\Magento\Cms\Model\Page');
   $_cmsPageURL = $_cmsPage->getIdentifier();
   return $_cmsPageURL;
}
```

}

And call in phtml:

```
$_Helper = $this->helper('Your\Namespace\Helper\Data');

$_pageIdentifier = $_Helper->getCurrentPageIdentifier();

echo $_pageIdentifier;
```

Hope this can help your.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following to get current page Identifier :

```
$this->getRequest()->getRouteName()
```

Comment: this doesn't always work: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115435/how-to-get-the-current-page-identifier-url-key-in-magento-2/115572#comment157301_115436

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the slug.

```
$currentUrl = $this->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true]);
$urlParts = explode("/", $currentUrl);
$slug = end($urlParts);
```

Answer (score -2):

If you need the query string (the bit after the ? in a URL), that part is in this variable:

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

Comment: this won't work if you have an url rewrite.  For example if  a page has the url key `page` but you have an url rewrite from `page1` to `page` and you call the url `page1` your code will return `page1` instead of `page`.